# Filling a form using a python script

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

I'm trying to write a python script that will fill a form on a website, send it, and after sending I want to search for a keyword on the resulting webpage.

More specifically, the form is: https://booking.elal.co.il/newBooking/changeOrder.jsp?LANG=EN&RESSYSTEMID=1

When I fill the form manually on the web, after I press the "continue" button I get kind of "processing page", and afterwards I get the webpage that I want to search on it the keyword.

I tried to use the script here: http://stockrt.github.io/p/handling-html-forms-with-python-mechanize-and-BeautifulSoup/ , but for some reason after submitting the form when I do: `print br.response().geturl()` I get the url of the "processing page", and not the url of the webpage I want to search on.

My Code:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import html2text

# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

# User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

# The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
br.open('https://booking.elal.co.il/newBooking/changeOrder.jsp?LANG=EN&RESSYSTEMID=1')

# Select the first (index zero) form
br.select_form(nr=0)

# User credentials
br.form['REC_LOC'] = '...'
br.form['DIRECT_RETRIEVE_LASTNAME'] = '...'

# Login
br.submit()

#Trying to print the webpage
html = br.response().read()
print html2text.html2text(html)
```

Is it possible to do what I want, and how can I do it?

Comment: Can you add code that you have?

Comment: Did you use br.set_handle_redirect(True) in your code?

Comment: That site might be using JavaScript to redirect.

Comment: use best language for the job. I suggest using javascript. If you are interested I can post the answer.

Comment: @Gunslinger_ : I did use this line in my code.

Comment: @rikAtee : That will help me, since I don't know javascript I tried to use python for this job.